# Can Van Allen Radiation belts act as a capacitor?

Tags: charge, capacitance

There are two Van Allen Belts at rougly 5000Km and 17000Km from the surface of the Earth each of them containing majority of one of the charges electrons and protons).

Can these belts like a capacitors.

Comment: I don't see why not. Anybody got an idea why the classification would be inappropriate?

Comment: @CuriousOne, Because the lower belt is near to upper atmosphere which is itself charged